# Add value to database without using forms in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am new to django and am stuck at a very basic level.
I want to create a model that stores the article posted by the the user. In the model I am able to save my article but how can I save the user id in that model.
On submitting this form only the title and body are saved.

My models.py file is as follows:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=169)
    Body = models.TextField()
    Author_id = models.CharField(max_length=3)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Title
```

My forms.py is as follows:

```
class AddArticle(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('Title', 'Body')
```

and my views.py is:

```
def UploadArticle(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = AddArticle(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            Article.Author_id = request.user.id #I guess my mistake lies here, but how to avoid it
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/articles/all')
        else:
            form = AddArticle()

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form']=AddArticle()
    return render_to_response('add.html', args)
```

Any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the article instance first, [commit explained in docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

```
article = form.save(commit=False)
```

then assign the author

```
article.Author = request.user
```

creating an Author field will automatically create an Author_id field in your table. I think if you create your field named Author_id it could create an Author_Id_id field?  It's safer in some ways to work with objects ie 'User' instance then it is to work with integers ie user.id

```
article.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Change 
`Author_id = models.CharField(max_length=3)` 
to 
`Author = models.ForeignKey(User)`

Then do what dm03514 is suggesting